# How to replace words in the middle of sentences in a large text using Notepad++ (followed by certain words or not)

Tags: notepad++

I have tried to replace all words followed by "SRL" with xxx

I have used:

Ctrl+H

Find what: (\w+) SRL

Replace with: (xxx)

check Match case

check Wrap around

check Regular expression

Replace all

Instead of replacing I receive a message in dialog box : "Are you sure you want to replace all occurences in : for file type: *.*? and does nothing either I click ok or cancel. If I repeat the click on replace all I receive the same message.

Thanks,
B.A.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1586329/edit) and add sample text and expected result.

Comment: No space after (\w+)SRL. I'm also not sure if the parenthesis are needed. Is there a checkbox that says "Regular Expressions"? Not all editors support his. You can in that case just try search for "SRL " with a space after - and without the quotation marks. Maybe take a screenshot of your dialog box and post it in your question - that way most of the unknowns will be clear... also perhaps quote a snippet of your data.